# Laravel Database migrations Schema builder custom column type

Tags: laravel, laravel-schema-builder

I am trying to create migrations with Laravel but I am in a situation where I need custom column type since the one I want isn't included in schema builder , which is "POLYGON". So I want to know, how I can create my custom column type, other than those that are already in the Schema builder.

What I want would look like this in SQL statement:

> alter table `xxx` add `polygon` POLYGON not null

Is it possible to do it by myself or I am forced to use some library like [this](https://github.com/shiftonelabs/laravel-nomad)?

I know that I can do like this:

```
DB::statement('ALTER TABLE country ADD COLUMN polygon POLYGON');
```

but it leads me to the error that the table doesn't exist.

Comment: The table doesn't exist error is because you're trying to do the `DB::statement()` alter table inside the `Schema::create('country')` closure. At that point, the table indeed does not exist yet. Simply call `DB::statement()` after.

Comment: @JoelMellon Yep, that could be the case and I suggest question seekers to first try that. But I can not remember how I solved it or what was the problem.

Answer (score 5):

There is no built in way to do this but you can achieve a good result with minimal code.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Grammars\Grammar;

// Put this in a service provider's register function.
Grammar::macro('typePolygon', function (Fluent $column) {
    return 'POLYGON';
});
 
// This belongs in a migration.
Schema::create('my_table', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->addColumn('polygon', 'my_foo');
});
```

The key is to add a function with the name `typePolygon` to the Grammar class because this function is what determines the actual type used by the particular DBMS. We achieve this by adding a macro to the Grammar.

I have written a blog post about how to extend this solution to any custom type: https://hbgl.dev/add-columns-with-custom-types-in-laravel-migrations/

Comment: Grammar not working for me:
Method Illuminate\Database\Schema\Grammars\PostgresGrammar::typeStatus does not exist.

Comment: @hGBI on a brand new laravel 8 project I just created a migration to "my_table" and copied and pasted your code: https://gist.github.com/gilbertoalbino/d577db94057a98c653a72e0d638db31e

Comment: @GilbertoAlbino I cannot reproduce the error on my side. I also created a new Laravel project, created a new migration, pasted your code, ran the migration, and it worked fine. If you ever find the cause of the problem, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you require spatial fields in your DB... I would consider via Packagist.org and search for **laravel-geo** (or equivalent) - which supports spatial column tyes inc Polygon. You could then use standard Laravel migration files for your custom fields -e.g.

```
$table->polygon('column_name');
```

In your UP function in your migration file...